# Python Tree, keep splitting a number

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I want to create a Tree which represents possibility of a number that keeps splitting. If you are familiar with the game of nim that is what I'm trying to do. The number can not be split evenly. So if i had 6. The tree would be:

```
[6]
[1,5] | [2,4]
[1,1,4][1,2,3]|[1,2,3]
```

This would keep going. In [2,4] the 4 got split then sorter into [1,2,3] which would then be split to [1,1,2,2]. This is the code I have so far:

```
class Minimax:
    def __init__(self, nimState, minMaxLevel):
        self.state = nimState
        self.level = minMaxLevel
        self.child = []
        self.nim_results = []

    def split_nim(self, nimpile):
        x = [[i, nimpile - i] for i in range(1, (nimpile + 1) // 2)]
        return x

    def build(self):
        nim_list = self.split_nim(self.state)
        for i in nim_list:
            var1 = i
            print(var1)
            try:
                self.state = self.child[-1]
                var1_last = var1[-1]
                var1.remove(var1_last)
                var1.append(split(var1_last))
                self.nim_results.append(var1)
                self.build()
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

My split function looks good, as I can split it how I want it. For 6 it becomes, [1,5] and [2,4]. In the built function, Im trying to build a tree out of it and keep splitting. This is what I'm having issues with. Ideally the output should be:

```
\-[6] MAX
    + [1, 5]
    |  + [1, 1, 4]
    |  |  \-[1, 1, 1, 3] MIN
    |  |     \-[1, 1, 1, 1, 2] MAX
    |  \-[1, 2, 3] MAX
    |     \-[1, 1, 2, 2] MIN
    \-[2, 4] MIN
       \-[1, 2, 3] MAX
          \-[1, 1, 2, 2] MIN
```

However, right now I'm just trying to split and build a tree.

Comment: How do you go from `[2,4]` to `[1,2,3]`?  If that's allowed, then why not `[1,1,4]`?  What do you mean by not split evenly?  Isn't `[1,1,2,2]` split evenly?

Comment: @BrendanAbel only splitting the number on the right.

Comment: What would the tree look like for `[3, 4]`?  Would you break the `3` and the `4` down at the same time? Or just one at a time

Comment: @BrendanAbel 4 first then 3, so one at a time